# How to sort a array descending order by key in php?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have an array like this

```
 $myval = array('name1'=>'google', 'name5'=>'yahoo', 'name3'=>'facebook','name2'=>'twitter','name4'=>'linkedin');
```

I want the output like this

```
name5 = yahoo
name4 = linkedin
name3 = facebook
name2 = twitter
name1 = google
```

I need my outpur as array key descending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use krsort() for this

```
krsort($myval);
```

For more php array sort you can refer http://www.techyline.com/php-sorting-array-with-unique-value/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [krsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) "Sorts an array by key in reverse order, maintaining key to data correlations. This is useful mainly for associative arrays. " like this:

```
$myval = array(
    'name1'=>'google', 
    'name5'=>'yahoo', 
    'name3'=>'facebook',
    'name2'=>'twitter',
    'name4'=>'linkedin');

krsort($myval);

print_r($myval);
```